# Optimizing memory consumption of regex in Go

Tags: regex, go, optimization, memory

I'm running with huge memory issues when using regex in Go:

```
Showing top 20 nodes out of 34
      flat  flat%   sum%        cum   cum%
    1.53GB 25.03% 25.03%     1.53GB 25.03%  regexp/syntax.(*compiler).inst
    1.43GB 23.29% 48.31%     1.43GB 23.29%  regexp/syntax.(*parser).newRegexp
    1.10GB 17.99% 66.31%     1.10GB 17.99%  regexp.onePassCopy
    0.53GB  8.67% 74.97%     0.53GB  8.67%  regexp/syntax.(*Regexp).Simplify
    0.39GB  6.44% 81.41%     0.90GB 14.74%  regexp.makeOnePass
    0.29GB  4.76% 86.17%     0.29GB  4.76%  regexp.newQueue
    0.19GB  3.13% 89.30%     0.22GB  3.54%  regexp.makeOnePass.func1
    0.17GB  2.79% 92.09%     6.10GB 99.54%  regexp.compile
    0.14GB  2.22% 94.31%     0.25GB  4.09%  regexp/syntax.(*parser).collapse
    0.14GB  2.21% 96.52%     0.14GB  2.21%  regexp/syntax.(*parser).push
    0.10GB  1.66% 98.17%     1.80GB 29.37%  regexp/syntax.Parse
    0.04GB  0.69% 98.86%     0.10GB  1.59%  regexp/syntax.(*compiler).init
         0     0% 98.86%     6.13GB   100%  bicctopostgres/app.Test_prepareRecordsToInsert
         0     0% 98.86%     6.10GB 99.54%  bicctopostgres/app.TypeIs
         0     0% 98.86%     6.10GB 99.54%  bicctopostgres/app.evalColumn
         0     0% 98.86%     6.11GB 99.74%  bicctopostgres/app.getColumnsHeaderData
         0     0% 98.86%     1.42GB 23.12%  bicctopostgres/app.isDate
         0     0% 98.86%     0.61GB 10.00%  bicctopostgres/app.isInteger
         0     0% 98.86%     1.09GB 17.85%  bicctopostgres/app.isReal
         0     0% 98.86%     2.98GB 48.58%  bicctopostgres/app.isTimestamp
```

I'm building a program to parse csv files, check each column if it is empty and data type (this last bit is made with regex), generate Postgres tables and load the records. The columns with no data are ignored when creating the DB tables.

But I have this huge bottleneck that for a mere 2000 records I'm ending using 6GB of memory just for regex related stuff.

This is an example of a function for checking whether the data is timestamp:

```
//isTimestamp returns true if the string is exacly: 9999-99-99 99:99:99.999999 .
func isTimestamp(s *string) bool {
    e := `(?i)^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{6}$`
    var isDesired = regexp.MustCompile(e)
    return isDesired.MatchString(*s)
}
```

And then the main function that checks for the types is:

```
//TypeIs returns the underlying data type of the string, if it's a string also returns the string length, otherwise is zero.
func TypeIs(s *string) (dataType string, stringLength int) {
    if isInteger(s) {
        return "INTEGER", 0
    }
    if isReal(s) {
        return "REAL", 0
    }
    if isDate(s) {
        return "DATE", 0
    }
    if isTimestamp(s) {
        return "TIMESTAMP", 0
    }
    return "TEXT", len(*s)
}
```

Perhaps my regex statements are too bad? They work, but perhaps it's too brute-force.

Any tips? Thanks!

Comment: You have a static regular expression, but you're recompiling it every time the function runs unnecessarily. Just compile it once and save it in a package var to reuse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you compile the regexp outside of the function?

```
var isDesired = regexp.MustCompile(`(?i)^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{6}$`)

func isTimestamp(s *string) bool {
    return isDesired.MatchString(*s)
}
```

Comment: @Gabriel was this the reason for your memory spike or did this modification helped to resolve your memory issue to some extent.